# Can I reference a hundreds value of a number from a cell in Apple Numbers?

Tags: numbers

For example, A1 has 12,345.00 I want A2 to output 345.00. Is this possible?

Comment: In Excel it would be `=MOD(A1;1000)`. Not in front of a Mac right now so I can't check whether Numbers supports this as well.

Comment: @nohillside That worked splendidly. I will study this MOD function. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the module function for this. In A2 enter

```
=MOD(A1;1000)
```